# Hotkey for All Users to Access Application in Session ID 0

Tags: c#, session, user-interface, startup

1. I want to run an Application at system startup.
2. I know it will run under Session 0.
3. I want System-Wide (works for All Users) Hotkey
4. This Hotkey Shows/Hides a GUI that is populated by the Application
5. As an example, Deepfreeze by Faronics does this exact thing. It runs under Session 0 and no matter which user you log in as you can press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>ALT</kbd> <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> <kbd>F6</kbd> and bring up a GUI. I know Deepfreeze is not .NET just fyi.

Who among you knows how to replicate this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have two processes, this is how system services operate. The first process is the service itself. The second process is the GUI and it is started when a user logs in to Windows. Then these two processes communicate using named pipes or any other inter process communication means.

I recommend you to read a few chapters of any book devoted to services programming, because this is very basic information you find there.